# Why don't glibc malloc thread local arenas

Tags: multithreading, malloc, glibc

glibc malloc assigns each thread only one arena. Why don't malloc simply thread local arena to avoid locking?

I have tried searching over Google and have found 0 answers related to this question.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your point but memory can be deleted from a thread that is not the same that the one that did the malloc. Thread local cannot work in that case unless others thread can access to it which means a lock/atomic are mandatory unless there is some late deletion queue. AFAIK, the deletion queue is a method used by some rare allocator and it has a big default: the deletion thread needs to be scheduled for the allocation to be performed. This delay causes a MT allocation+deallocation loop to be quite harmful (risk of OOM).

Comment: This topic is quite advanced so you will mostly find useful information in the code of the allocators, the mailing lists and *research paper*. There is not many website explaining how such allocator work and why they did such choices (not to mention the code change over time).